# Play logging system

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

I'm a bit confused about the logging system in Play.

Without importing any logging library, I added this to my code:

```
Logger.debug("Data is: " + data)
```

It didn't cause a compilation error but at the same time, it didn't print anything in the terminal window where I started the activator(where I typed `activator run`).

After looking here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaLogging, I also tried:

```
val logger = Logger(this.getClass)
logger.debug("Data is: " + data)
```

However, again nothing is printed.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Logger.debug("Data is: " + data) should work. Make sure you imported the correct logger. Tip: As you use Scala all the framework tooling is below play.api

Comment: You have also probably read https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger

Comment: When using Logger, you are in fact logging using the application logger. So if you haven't overridden logback.xml your message should be displayed in the console.

Comment: @JonasAnso As said here playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger, I imported `import play.api.Logger` but it had no effect. I can't find any file called `logback.xml` in my project.

Comment: The default level for application in dev mode is INFO. You will see your messages if you increase the level Logger.info("your data")

Comment: If you want to set a different level, just override logback.xml with your preferences.

Comment: Yeah, it turnsout `Logger.info` works but not `Logger.debug`. Strange.

Comment: I have reviewed the code and I have created an issue. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5842

Comment: Most people do not have this problem because it is very usual to override the logback.xml to define custom logging configuration. And I recommend you do the same.

Answer (score 1):

there is few log level You can set in application.conf according documentation.

```
# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG

# Logger for a third party library
logger.org.springframework=INFO
```

Try set log level to debug in Your application.conf

Comment: What is the purpose of this configuration?

Comment: This response is a bit outdated, only works until play 2.3. For play 2.4 onwards you have to override logback.xml   https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Logging

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is an issue in the default configuration for the logger in DEV mode https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5842
The default level for applications is INFO so debug messages are not shown.

While that issue is not fixed the workaround is to override logback.xml 
Following the example in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger that defines the log level for application as DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

1.Add below in build.sbt:
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0"

2.Import following in your controller:
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger

3.Use
private val logger = Logger(this.getClass)
logger.warn("your messages in here.")